# How to declare an array of 4 bits in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I need an array to hold a 4-bit number. It is neither an input or an output, just an intermediary value necessary for calculations. How would this be declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For synthesis, you would use either a register or a wire, depending on what you needed it for.

```
reg  [3:0] my_reg;
```

or

```
wire [3:0] my_wire;
```

If you will use this value in an always block, you need to declare it as a reg.

If you are using it for combinational logic, not inside an always block, you would declare it as a wire.  This would be used with an assign statements or in a port list.

Answer (score 4):

You mean that you need a variable?

`reg [3:0] mynumber;`